# R: How to batch create multiple copies of an .R script file with different variable names?

Tags: r, replace, batch-processing

This is my first post here and I am trying to follow the guidelines to the best of my knowledge, so please bear with me.

I want to create a large number of similar .R script files which differ only in the variable names used and in the strings that mention these variables. Of course, this can also be achieved via search & replace but I was wondering whether there is a more convenient solution to create a bunch of them more quickly.

Let's take this made up script (the actual data is irrelevant here):

```
prefix.AnExemplaryRandomVariable <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
AnotherRandomVariable.suffix <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 10, sd = 3)

plot(prefix.AnExemplaryRandomVariable, AnotherRandomVariable.suffix,
      type = "p", pch = "*", xlab = "An Exemplary Random Variable",
      ylab = "Another Random Variable", main = "A plot of An Exemplary
      Random Variable and Another Random Variable")
```

My idea was to define two vectors with k new names for each one.

```
newNamesVar1 <- c("prefix.FirstVariable", "prefix.SomeData")
newNamesVar2 <- c("SecondVariable.suffix", "CannotThinkOfMoreNames.suffix")
```

The result I am looking for are k new .R files that look like this:

```
prefix.FirstVariable <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
SecondVariable.suffix <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 10, sd = 3)

plot(prefix.FirstVariable, SecondVariable.suffix, type = "p",
      pch = "*", xlab = "First Variable", ylab = "Second Variable",
      main = "A plot of First Variable and Second Variable")
```

and

```
prefix.SomeData <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
CannotThinkOfMoreNames.suffix <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 10, sd = 3)

plot(prefix.SomeData, CannotThinkOfMoreNames.suffix, type = "p",
      pch = "*", xlab = "Some Data", ylab = "Cant Think Of More Names",
      main = "A plot of Some Data and Cannot Think Of More Names")
```

I see the following two challenges:

1. Replacing the original variable names with the corresponding vector entries
2. Checking any strings for similarities with the original variable names and replacing them while keeping the syntax and format (case sensitivity, spacing,...) intact.

This is the first time I am trying to use R for anything beyond actual data analysis, so I cannot even provide much of a code draft. I was able to get the variable names with `ls()`, but I do not have the slightest clue about what to do next, mainly because the changes are not to be applied to the file that is currently active but to a completely new one.

Any solutions, tips, hints or nudges are appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: It works, and I won't forget to accept it but I'd first like to check whether I run into any issues when trying to apply it to my actual code. Will I still be able to ask follow-up questions after accepting an answer?

Comment: You could ask a new question.  It is better to ask a single question per post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one method.

**Setup** for this answer:

```r
writeLines('
prefix.AnExemplaryRandomVariable <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
AnotherRandomVariable.suffix <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 10, sd = 3)

plot(prefix.AnExemplaryRandomVariable, AnotherRandomVariable.suffix,
      type = "p", pch = "*", xlab = "An Exemplary Random Variable",
      ylab = "Another Random Variable",
      main = "A plot of An Exemplary Random Variable and Another Random Variable")
', "template.R")
```

**Table** of replacement values to use, where the column name indicates the template string, and the column values are the replacement text.

```r
replacements <- data.frame(
  "An Exemplary Random Variable" = c("First Variable", "Some Data"),
  "Another Random Variable" = c("Second Variable", "Cannot Think Of More Names"),
  check.names = FALSE
)
replacements
#   An Exemplary Random Variable    Another Random Variable
# 1               First Variable            Second Variable
# 2                    Some Data Cannot Think Of More Names
```

**The Work** that replaces each template string from the `template.R`, makes the replacement, ultimately storing into new files.

```r
code <- readLines("template.R")
for (row in seq_len(nrow(replacements))) {
  newcode <- code
  for (col in seq_along(replacements)) {
    if (!is.na(replacements[row,col])) {
      ptn1 <- colnames(replacements)[col] # original
      ptn2 <- gsub(" +", "", ptn1)        # "Title Case Sentence" to "TitleCaseSentence"
      repl1 <- replacements[row,col]
      repl2 <- gsub(" +", "", repl1)
      newcode <- gsub(paste0("\\b", ptn1, "\\b"), repl1,
                      gsub(paste0("\\b", ptn2, "\\b"), repl2, newcode))
    }
  }
  writeLines(newcode, sprintf("code_%s.R", row))
}
```

This has the added functionality that if the replacement string (value within a particular cell in `replacements`) is `NA`, then no replacement will be attempted for that pattern.

Output:

- `code_1.R`

  ```r
  prefix.FirstVariable <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  SecondVariable.suffix <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 10, sd = 3)

  plot(prefix.FirstVariable, SecondVariable.suffix,
        type = "p", pch = "*", xlab = "First Variable",
        ylab = "Second Variable",
        main = "A plot of First Variable and Second Variable")
  ```
- `code_2.R`

  ```r
  prefix.SomeData <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  CannotThinkOfMoreNames.suffix <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 10, sd = 3)

  plot(prefix.SomeData, CannotThinkOfMoreNames.suffix,
        type = "p", pch = "*", xlab = "Some Data",
        ylab = "Cannot Think Of More Names",
        main = "A plot of Some Data and Cannot Think Of More Names")
  ```

Limitations:

- pattern strings must be contiguous on their own line, so notice that I changed the template `main=` string to not span two lines
- pattern strings must not be immediately preceded/followed by letters; the use of `\\b` (regex word boundary) allows for some characters (like the literal `.`), but this makes no attempt to be any fancier

**Edited**: after I finished, I realized that it might be easier to define the patterns and replacement strings *with the spaces*, and then remove the spaces for the second (TitleCase) pattern. This way one avoids some ambiguity and trickery of splitting a string by title-case. It also allows for your patterns or replacements to be *not* title case.